Data Streams Last Run Status is not coming as Success
I am working on Bring External Data into the Contact Page Layout
I have enabled the Data Streams but as mentioned in the step, I am not able to see the Last Run Status of the steams as Success.
Below is snapshot from trailhead:

I have waited more than 15 minutes but still not done.
Does anyone aware of this?

It sometimes take more time to ingest. It took more than 45 minutes for me:

